# How do I calculate this using integers or rounding up inside each bracket?

Tags: java, android, integer, double, rounding

*This is coded in Java in android studio*

So I'm a total noob at coding and I have a problem with this damage calculator I'm trying to create for this mmorpg I play based on the calculation formula the developer has shared...

So this is how I initially wrote the program:

```
double skill, bonus, level, attack, min, max, avg, min2, avg2, max2;

EditText txtskill;
EditText txtbonus;
EditText txtlevel;
EditText txtattack;
TextView resmin;
TextView resavg;
TextView resmax;
TextView resmin2;
TextView resavg2;
TextView resmax2;
Button btncalculate;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtskill = findViewById(R.id.txtskill);
    txtbonus = findViewById(R.id.txtbonus);
    txtlevel = findViewById(R.id.txtlevel);
    txtattack = findViewById(R.id.txtattack);
    resmin = findViewById(R.id.txtmin);
    resavg = findViewById(R.id.txtavg);
    resmax = findViewById(R.id.txtmax);
    resmin2 = findViewById(R.id.txtmin2);
    resavg2 = findViewById(R.id.txtavg2);
    resmax2 = findViewById(R.id.txtmax2);

    btncalculate = findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            skill = Double.parseDouble(txtskill.getText().toString());
            bonus = Double.parseDouble(txtbonus.getText().toString());
            level = Double.parseDouble(txtlevel.getText().toString());
            attack = Double.parseDouble(txtattack.getText().toString());
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

            min = ((skill + bonus) / 2 + level / 4 + attack) * 0.9;
            max = ((skill + bonus) / 2 + level / 4 + attack) * 1.1;
             avg = (min + max) / 2;
             min2 = min * 1.05;
             max2 = max * 1.05;
             avg2 = avg * 1.05;



            resmin.setText(df.format(min));
            resavg.setText(df.format(avg));
            resmax.setText(df.format(max));
            resmin2.setText(df.format(min2));
            resavg2.setText(df.format(avg2));
            resmax2.setText(df.format(max2));

        }
    });

}
```

Which works just fine... but the problem is that it turned out that the actual damage output in the game is actually calculated either using integers or rounding things up inside every bracket...

So this is how i tried to fix it:

```
int skill, bonus, level, attack, min, max, avg, min2, avg2, max2;

EditText txtskill;
EditText txtbonus;
EditText txtlevel;
EditText txtattack;
TextView resmin;
TextView resavg;
TextView resmax;
TextView resmin2;
TextView resavg2;
TextView resmax2;
Button btncalculate;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtskill = findViewById(R.id.txtskill);
    txtbonus = findViewById(R.id.txtbonus);
    txtlevel = findViewById(R.id.txtlevel);
    txtattack = findViewById(R.id.txtattack);
    resmin = findViewById(R.id.txtmin);
    resavg = findViewById(R.id.txtavg);
    resmax = findViewById(R.id.txtmax);
    resmin2 = findViewById(R.id.txtmin2);
    resavg2 = findViewById(R.id.txtavg2);
    resmax2 = findViewById(R.id.txtmax2);

    btncalculate = findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            skill = Integer.parseInt(txtskill.getText().toString());
            bonus = Integer.parseInt(txtbonus.getText().toString());
            level = Integer.parseInt(txtlevel.getText().toString());
            attack = Integer.parseInt(txtattack.getText().toString());


            min = ((skill + bonus) / 2 + level / 4 + attack) * 0.9;
            max = ((skill + bonus) / 2 + level / 4 + attack) * 1.1;
             avg = (min + max) / 2;
             min2 = min * 1.05;
             max2 = max * 1.05;
             avg2 = avg * 1.05;
```

//^^At this part where I start using the values to do the calculations the debugger is telling me that it's expecting a double

```
            resmin.setText(min));
            resavg.setText(avg));
            resmax.setText(max));
            resmin2.setText(min2));
            resavg2.setText(avg2));
            resmax2.setText(max2));

        }
    });

}
```

So my question is how does one make this program use integers or atleast round everything up inside each bracket?
Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

start with the revert back to doubles in your definition of variables from

```
int skill, bonus, level, attack, min, max, avg, min2, avg2, max2;
```

back to

```
double skill, bonus, level, attack, min, max, avg, min2, avg2, max2;
```

Then the second step will be rounding all numbers before setting them back to the UI comopnents like:

```
resmin.setText(Math.round(min));
```

etc.

Comment: Btw. good idea is to round only the final result, not the particular one due to the cumulative round error

Comment: no no, the problem is that I need the rounding error so I can output the same final numbers as the game uses

Comment: In that case move Math.round(x) where you need and use integer division. That means you have on the left and right side of equation integers, same like as operands.  integer = integer / integer. Return type of Math.round(x) is int, so you will be able to replace it where you need. Start with that you revert to your  definition of variables as ints, then you will replace the division operands with Math.round(x) and you will see, that the number of errors about expecting doubles will decrease

Comment: you will result with something like this: 

int min = new Long(Math.round((Math.round(skill + bonus) / 2 + Math.round(level) / 4 + Math.round(attack)) * 0.9)).intValue();

Comment: doesn't Math.round () round up inside the brackets?

Comment: also it tells me to use Long.valueOf instead of new Long

Comment: Anyways this method is way too complicated to be the actual method the damage is calculated.... the reason I tought it was this way is because my current calculator output the damage as 204.7 but the actual damage was 206... then we tried to add the current level and skill progression % as decimals to it and it came out as 205.3 which should round down...

Comment: Those numbers aren't the actual numbers but you get the idea right?